Synthetic Control for intermittent treatment
I'm exploring the application of the synthetic control method (SCM) to analyze the impact of intermittent treatments or interventions on a target outcome. I'm interested in understanding how SCM can be effectively utilized when the treatment is applied intermittently rather than continuously. In my case I have a lot of units to work with, but almost all of them have received the treatment in some time period.
What I'm currently doing to create the synthetic control is identify the dates during which my test unit did not receive the treatment, and use only those to attempt to create a weighted average of my control units. Essentially I treat non-treatment periods as my pre-treatment.
Firstly, is there any library that allows for intermittent/on-off treatment in the data? I was unable to find any, and it makes me wonder if I'm violating any underlying assumptions of SC and how applicable the method is to my problem.

Have you considered using SparceSC?
